# Will downvote reversal script allow special cases like site flooding with inappropriate question?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, down-votes, serial-voting

I've just downvoted a bunch of questions of that user: https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/users/36946/damodaran

The reason: he posted questions in the Area51 discussion, that are not discussion, but sample questions for the site. I don't know what he wanted to achieve, but I've downvoted to prevent such flooding the site with inappropriate questions. All of this questions are already closed.

Will downvote-reversal script trigger in that case, or they are already taken into account in algorithm?

Comment: The script can't detect intent, yet.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Downvoting doesn't prevent anything. It also doesn't clean up anything. Flag one of them and report it to a moderator. The script may or may not take your downvotes away, but that doesn't really matter. When the questions are deleted your downvotes will be deleted with them.

Comment: Isn't it so, that having many very downvoted questions can lead to automatic ban? And makes deleting questions easier?

Comment: deliberately downvoting many questions from the same user hoping to cause an automatic ban for that user seems like a very bad idea indeed. You can't be sure it will work, and if it does work, it will leave the user unable to learn the norms of the site and move forward properly. Don't do it.

Comment: No, I didn't deliberately downvoted posts from that user. I've deliberately downvoted all bad questions from the main page, which happened to be from one user, because he has literally flooded the main page with his questions.

Comment: @volkerjaan I don't think the post bans even exist there. They are off by default on sites and have to be turned on manually by the staff if it is deemed necessary to do so. Even so, Kate is right here. You should just flag them and not worry about the votes.

Comment: _" When the questions are deleted your downvotes will be deleted with them."_ -- per my recollection, reversal script kicks in even when posts are deleted. It once happened at Programmers that I quickly DVed 3 spam posts from the same account in the row (along with flagging), these were quickly deleted, but next day I noticed "serial voting reversed" in reputation tab